# My colleague got his account deleted because he voted many of my questions and answers

Tags: discussion, voting, accounts

The stackoverflow admin sent me a message like:

> There are clear signs of falsified accounts being used to artificially inflate your reputation. The offending accounts have been removed and the votes invalidated.

How can they say it was artificially inflated if that was my colleague doing it (obviously becaue we work together and we ask and answer the questions together because they are usefult to both of us, and we use my profile because I have more reputation and more privileges)

Comment: So you're freely admitting that your coworker is using both accounts, and using them to vote on each other's posts.  Case closed I guess.

Comment: It's generally not a good idea to have your co-workers upvote your questions and answers frequently, ***especially*** if it's all done from the same office (same IP addresses will probably be used), because of how easily it looks like voting-fraud. Even if you don't get caught for voting-fraud, you have a high chance of being caught by [the serial-voting algorithm](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253154/456814), which will remove all of the votes anyways. **So it's useless. Don't do it.**

Comment: But there's an interesting potential feature-request here: combo-accounts, where a team can work together. hmmm, may be useful

Comment: @Coffee you mean work together to upvote each other's questions and answers? Sounds a lot like voting abuse to me `:P` By the way, I need more Coffee to go along with my Cupcake `:/`

Comment: hehe, coffee with cupcakes indeeed

Comment: I thought it was not abuse because the upvote in SO is given if you find the question useful. and the fact that we both use the answer to the questions is a clear sign of them being useful to both of us. SO is a tool for helping each others, and if helping a colleague is not allowed then I don't see the reason. I find an answer for me and he find it useful and he rewards me, as easy as that.

Comment: "SO is a tool for helping each others, and if helping a colleague is not allowed then I don't see the reason." You know what an straw man fallacy is? Google for it. Point is, helping your colleague is allowed, only mutually voting up your answers is not.

Comment: Maybe a joint account thing that lets you join accounts together to avoid being able to vote on anything that they or join-tee posts.

Answer (score 28):

I am the one who acted on your account and the one that was deleted. As you noted, the message you got said:

> There are **clear signs** of falsified accounts being used to artificially inflate your reputation. The offending accounts have been removed and the votes invalidated.

Emphasis added. But let me add more: The signs were *clear* that it was a falsified account. *Absolutely, completely clear*. Your question here sort of admits as much. You also say:

> How can they say it was artificially inflated if that was my colleague doing it (obviously becaue we work together and we ask and answer the questions together because they are usefult to both of us, and we use my profile because I have more reputation and more privileges)

If you were both using your profile, there would have been nothing fishy about the other one, and no cross votes. Yet there were; 590 reputation points worth.

Comment: I'm going to go out on a limb and say that they probably share links via IM or email. But the sharing of the profiles does sound fishy. Case closed.

Comment: I thought it was not abuse because the upvote in SO is given if you find the question useful. and the fact that we both use the answer to the questions is a clear sign of them being useful to both of us. SO is a tool for helping each others, and if helping a colleague is not allowed then I don't see the reason. I find an answer for me and he find it useful and he rewards me, as easy as that.

Comment: @MaurizioIndenmark By that reasoning, I should have all nine of my co-workers create accounts here and up-vote all the answers I post. Even though my answers may/may not be any more useful than the other answers people post, that would give me and my answers an incredible advantage, and would be wholly antithetical to the very purpose of the voting system. My answers *are* useful to my co-workers in a way, and represent the benefit I bring to them by my work and knowledge here. That itself 'helps' them. That's totally separate from the usefulness of my answers to *this site*.

Comment: But also keep in mind my first couple paragraphs.

Comment: For your in-comment example, how is that different than people recognizing familar names an upvoting them? Feels like a lot of SO-famous people get significantly higher votes across the board. ie http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23679379/argument-type-lambda-expression-is-not-assignable-to-parameter-type-int-error/23679459#23679459m where a (slightly) later comment got upvoted much more than an equivalent one. It sounds like an example of proximity being OPs issue, rather than anything else. I understand that I'm conflating popularity with vote spamming.

Comment: @TankorSmash If you don't intuitively understand the difference, I can't imagine how to explain it.

Comment: @AndrewBarber In OPs situation, the friend knows him and upvotes, in my example, ~5 people recognize the answerer and have unevenly voted. The difference then is plainly either that the OP is missing the respectability the answerer has, or because he has been followed around by one person. Admittedly it's not the same people following Skeet around, but I feel like it's similar enough to compare.

Comment: @TankorSmash Please read my answer *very carefully*. What you say is debatable, but it does not remotely apply here, regardless what the OP claims.

Answer (score 22):

The close personal relationship that you have with a [sock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sockpuppet_(Internet)) has no bearing on the determination of voter fraud perpetrated by said sock.  Were that the case, everyone could simply claim that "This sock is a close, personal friend of mine," and be immune from scrutiny.

To put it another way, we don't really care how fond you are of that sock.

Comment: I'm keeping my warm, fuzzy, wool socks far, far away from you.

Comment: In case you're not familiar with [the usage of "sock"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sockpuppet_(Internet)) in this context...

Comment: So following your logic it is wrong to go to the profile of your favourite Developer in the world and vote many of his answers because you think he just deserves it for all the help that gives to the community and to you? I did that with Jeremy Foster profile. Do I deserve my account to be cancelled now? Put it simple, am I a sock because I vote the answers of a person I like??

Comment: @MaurizioIndenmark: For accounts in good standing, these kinds of votes will simply be reversed automatically by the nightly script.  I've seen it happen before; that's the price you pay for their being people who create accounts solely for the purpose of upvoting their main account.

Answer (score 22):

If your colleague would like his account restored, [he needs to contact the Stack Exchange Community team](https://stackoverflow.com/contact).

It bears mentioning (though I'm not sure why I need to say this) that you should not be voting for a person based on who they are.  If you find yourself going to someone's profile page and voting on their questions, you're probably going to get yourself in trouble.

If you keep your votes an "Arms Length" away, you'll be fine.

If you don't... well.. you risk *exactly what happened.*

Comment: Yup! I understand that there are people who genuinely don't realize what is "wrong" with the sort of behavior you describe, and the OP *suggests* was the case here. But like you allude to, it boggles my mind a little bit. I just instinctively *feel* like doing that is cheating. And FYI; I did see your deleted comment :)

Comment: So following your logic it is wrong to go to the profile of your favourite Developer in the world and vote many of his answers because you think he just deserves it for all the help that gives to the community and to you? I did that with Jeremy Foster profile. Do I deserve my account to be cancelled now?

Comment: @MaurizioIndenmark: Not necessarily canceled, but i'd hope at least that the fraud detection stuff notices your serial upvoting and reverses it.  The difference is, unless your favorite developer in the world happens to work with you, it doesn't stink of vote fraud -- it just smells a bit.  *Vote on posts, not people.*